# Neo4j very slow when executing query through PHP but very fast through webadmin

Tags: php, neo4j

I have the following problem.
I have written a query:

```
  MATCH (n:RealNode {gid:'58687'})-[:CONTAINS*..15]-(z) RETURN DISTINCT ID(z), z.id,n.id as InternalID
```

which I run through a PHP script (by sending a POST request). It takes ages to get a response and sometimes neo4j hangs.
I tried the same query in the Neo4j webadmin and I get the response in ms.

Any idea why in the first case the response takes so much time?

**EDITED**
This the request using CURL:

```
   $obj_id = $_POST['datastr'];
   $dataArr = array("query" => "MATCH (n {gid:'$obj_id'})-[:CONTAINS*..15]-(z) RETURN DISTINCT ID(z), z.id,n.id as InternalID");

  $data = json_encode($dataArr);
  $curl=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8','Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data),'X-Stream: true'));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher/');  
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); //type of request   
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data); // data to post
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return response as string
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  echo $response;
  curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: how do you send your query in Php? are you using a driver like neoclient? are you using a http library like guzzle? or do you just leverage Curl?

Comment: I use Curl to make the request. I edited my question with the CURL request.

Comment: Mmh you are using the old cypher endpoint, I guess you'll get better results by using the cypher transactional endpoint

Comment: What do you mean? Should I get my query with a transaction? Like: "STATEMENT" => MATCH (n {gid:'$obj_id'})-[:CONTAINS*..15]-(z) RETURN DISTINCT ID(z), z.id,n.id as InternalID" ??

Comment: I replied as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the legacy Cypher endpoint.

I recommend you to use the Cypher http transactional endpoint and to use query parameters.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html

Also you can make use of a php neo4j driver like [NeoClient](https://github.com/neoxygen/neo4j-neoclient) that will remove you the burden of curl and will provide a pretty response formatter.

Comment: Thanks. But I though I use Transcactions only to upload data to DB (e.g cretate nodes etc). I wrote a statement now that I get some results like but I don't know how to read the response of a query like this. Actually it gives me nothing back!

Comment: That's where a neo4j driver will help. For the query returning nothing you will need to provide more details like the debug of the curl request, something that show the http response

Comment: I am still not sure if I can send a transaction statement to retrieve data. There is nothing like this in the documentation. All the examples are related with creating nodes.

Comment: sure you can do it for retrieving data

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: For nice php setup and examples I suggest you to read this http://www.sitepoint.com/discover-graph-databases-neo4j-php/ and this http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-social-network-features-php-app-neo4j/